# textbox random line selection c#

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

lets say I have a multi-line textbox with 100 lines, how would you go about selecting one of those lines randomly in c# and putting that value in a string.

Comment: Should natural line breaks be taken into consideration?

Comment: its just a list of information, one item per line.

Comment: Why are you splitting up the values from the textbox.  The only reason for this is that the data is user generated data and not from a datasource? If the data is from a datasource why not use a dropdown list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.Next(0, textBox1.Lines.Length);
string line = textBox1.Lines[index];
```

Of course `r` should be a class or instance variable and not re-newed every time you need this, otherwise it won't be so random.

**Edit per comment:**

This uses the [`Random.Next()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) overload that allows you to specify a range from which you want to pick a (pseudo-) random number. The `0` is the *inclusive* lower bound of the range, `textBox1.Lines.Length` is the *exclusive* upper bound of the range (which means that that number itself won't be part of the range) - so you will get numbers from 0 to `textBox1.Lines.Length` -1.

Comment: can you explain what the 0 is? i think i understand the rest of the code.

Comment: It's asking for a random integer between 0 and the total line lengths.  Should be minus 1.

Comment: @Mike C: No it shouldn't - the upper boundary is **exclusive** so it will never return that number, see my edit for explanation.

Comment: @Mintuz: it is the start of the collection. C# counts from 0.